# Swift Protocol Extension with AssociatedType Constrained to Collection, Can't Use Subscript

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols, protocol-extension, swift3.2

I'm trying to write a protocol that conforms to the Collection Protocol, and it has an associatedType - Object and a property object.

```
protocol DDCDataSource: Collection
{
    associatedtype Object
    var object: Object {get set}
}
```

I want to add some default functionality for the case where Object also conforms to the Collection protocol, namely just directly return Object's implementation of these required Collection properties and functions. It seems like it all works except for Collection's requirement for a subscript.

> Cannot subscript a value of type 'Self.Object' with an index of type 'Self.Object.Index'

[image]

```
extension DDCDataSource where Object: Collection
{
    typealias Index = Object.Index

    var startIndex: Object.Index {
        get {
            return object.startIndex
        }
    }

    var endIndex: Object.Index {
        get {
            return object.endIndex
        }
    }

    subscript(position: Object.Index) -> Element
    {
        return object[position]
    }

    func index(after i: Object.Index) -> Object.Index {
        return object.index(after: i)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't use images, add a code snippet instead.

Comment: I added the tag swift 3.2 because it's specific to Xcode 9. On Xcode 8 you'd have _"Use of undeclared type 'Element'"_.

Comment: `extension DDCDataSource where Object:  RandomAccessCollection`, feels like a little better.

Comment: `return object[position] as! Element`

Comment: @Cœur: No, that would crash at runtime.

Comment: @MartinR That's normal to crash, for the same reasons as `_ = ["foo", "bar"][3]` would crash at runtime. Yet, we don't forbid Swift to implement subscripts that way.

Comment: @Cœur: I don't get what you mean. I have tested the code with an actual type conforming to DDCDataSource. Changing the return type or adding a type alias (as I suggested below) makes it compile *and run* as expected, but with `return object[position] as! Element` it crashes at runtime.

Comment: @MartinR With a valid index, it doesn't crash. I used `subscript(test position: Object.Index) -> Element { return object[position] as! Element }` and `extension Array: DDCDataSource { typealias Object = Array; var object: Array { get { return self } set { } } }`. Then I test and `print(["a", "b"][test: 1])` outputs **b** while `print(["a", "b"][test: 3])` gives a _fatal error: Index out of range_.

Comment: @Cœur:  I tested it with `struct MyDataSource: DDCDataSource { var object = [1, 2, 3] }` and `let mds = MyDataSource() ; print(mds[1])` – In your example,  `Object.Element` and `Self.Element` are identical, that is not the case in general.

Comment: @MartinR _Type 'MyDataSource' does not conform to protocol '_IndexableBase'_ and _Type 'MyDataSource' does not conform to protocol 'Collection'_. So your code doesn't build. Xcode 9 beta 6, Swift 3.2.

Comment: @Cœur: That is strange. I have added the full example below, it works for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short answer:** Change the return type of the subscript method
to `Object.Element`

```
subscript(position: Object.Index) -> Object.Element {
    return object[position]
}
```

or add a type alias (in a similar way as you did for the `Index` type)

```
typealias Element = Object.Element

subscript(position: Object.Index) -> Element {
    return object[position]
}
```

That makes the code compile and run as expected.

---

**Explanation:** The [`subscript` method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collection/1641358-subscript) of `Collection` is declared as

```
subscript(position: Self.Index) -> Self.Element { get }
```

where `Self.Index` and `Self.Element` are associated types
of `Collection. With your code

```
subscript(position: Object.Index) -> Element {
    return object[position]
}
```

the compiler infers `Self.Index` to be `Object.Index`, but there
is no relation between `Self.Element` and `Object.Element` (which is
returned by `object[position]`). The error becomes more apparent
if you add an explicit cast:

```
subscript(position: Object.Index) -> Element {
    return object[position] as Element
}
```

Now the compiler complains

> error: 'Self.Object.Element' is not convertible to 'Self.Element'; did you mean to use 'as!' to force downcast?

The correct solution is *not* the forced cast but to make the compiler
know that `Self.Element` is `Object.Element`, by adding a type alias
or by changing the return type

```
subscript(position: Object.Index) -> Object.Element {
    return object[position]
}
```

so that the compiler *infers* `DDCDataSource.Element` to be `Object.Element`.

---

**Full self-contained example:** (Swift 4, Xcode 9 beta 6)

(Note that you can omit the `get` keyword for read-only computed
properties.)

```
protocol DDCDataSource: Collection {
    associatedtype Object
    var object: Object { get set }
}

extension DDCDataSource where Object: Collection {
    var startIndex: Object.Index {
        return object.startIndex
    }

    var endIndex: Object.Index {
        return object.endIndex
    }

    subscript(position: Object.Index) -> Object.Element {
        return object[position]
    }

    func index(after i: Object.Index) -> Object.Index {
        return object.index(after: i)
    }
}

struct MyDataSource: DDCDataSource {
    var object = [1, 2, 3]
}

let mds = MyDataSource()
print(mds[1]) // 2

for x in mds { print(x) } // 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I think you should define `Element`,

Secondly, you use `object[position]`,  Object Conforms To Collection , but it is not of Collection Types . Obviously it is not Array.

> As [apple
>   says](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array): array
>   conforms to CustomDebugStringConvertible / CustomReflectable /
>   CustomStringConvertible / CVarArg /Decodable / Encodable /
>   ExpressibleByArrayLiteral /MutableCollection /RandomAccessCollection /
>   RangeReplaceableCollection

I think `extension DDCDataSource where Object: Array` is better.

And the element in array shall be `Element` defined. Just tips.

Comment: This is a protocol, the goal is to have it be very generic and allow classes/structs that use it to define Element. Also I want Object to work for all collection types and not just arrays.

Comment: Yes, the protocol is brief.   I try to simplify it . Somewhat divide  and conquer.  And thank you. I am new to Swift 4.  `Element`  seems weird to me. I got some , while not good as Martin R .  No down vote is nice.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
subscript(position:Object.Index) -> Element
    {
        var element: Element
        guard let elementObject = object[position] else {
            //handle the case of 'object' being 'nil' and exit the current scope
        }
        element = elementObject as! Element

    }
```

Comment: Does that really compile? `object[position]` is  not an optional.

Comment: Right, it's not an optional - but leaving out the guard statement and just returning object[position] as! Element would compile. As to whether it would crash or not -- I did not try to actually run it yet.